# How to commit from command line only content changes not property ones?

Tags: svn, commit

Developer fixes bug in a branch created from trunk. Then I test the branch and reintegrate back to trunk.

Lately I am also committing property changes. There are three files that I commit back to trunk over and over. I compared the content of the files in between revisions using svn and they are the same. Only some property changed.

**Q1:** is there any way so I would commit from command line only files that have `M` in the first column only when I do `svn st`?

**Q2:** Is there any way we can clean trunk or how to get rid of committing these three files over and over?

---- edit
svn st gives me

```
 M      .
 M      controllers/database/udfs/searchForNameContSrch.sql
 M      controllers/eduMoodleInterface
 M      controllers/main
 M      controllers/teaching
 M      lib/utils/EduMail.php
 M      lib/views/learning/progress/reverse_template_converter.php
M       pages/carer/carer_basepage.php
M       pages/common/contact_list_detail_basepage.php
M       pages/contact/contact_basepage.php
M       pages/staff/staff_basepage.php
M       pages/student/student_basepage.php
```

current solution is to revert the files that have M in the second column prior to commit. It works but is time consuming. Any other idea?

Comment: This is probably cheating and too inelegant to be an answer, but I occasionally copy-and-paste the files I want into vi, remove the initial-letters-column, then hold down shift-J until all the file names are on the same line, then prepend "svn ci -mBlahBlah" to the front of that single line, and finally execute that line as a shell command.

Comment: :-) it's kind of the same like reverting the files I don't want to commit. They should't be committed, we don't know why the properties were changed anyway.

Comment: Q1: You can use Tortoise to do that kind of job. Select in the checkbox the files you want to commit.
Q2:The same tool that a respond on Q1, Tortoise do that cleanup for you, if you have multiple files you can clean them with this tool.

Comment: I need to use command line solution because I code web based application to do merging where I use command line...

Comment: Since you `don't know why the properties were changed`, the main problem may be existence of property changes. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the root cause. I don't know how to make it so it won't happen again and again. I compared the files and if there are going to be committed again I am happy not to commit them without thinking. I do agree that it would be the best to solve the root cause but I do not know how and I even know why this is happening. I am not a developer that "probably" caused that.

Comment: Even if you don't know *why*, do you know *which* properties are getting changed?

Answer (score 7):

I'd be more inclined to figure out what's going on with the properties and solve that problem than try to just ignore them.  That said, at the end of this answer, there's a one-liner that will speed up your revert process if you're on linux.

For the sake of this answer, I've set a property on one file ( `window.c` ) and modified another ( `window.h` ).

```
svn status
 M      window.c
M       window.h
```

The main commands svn use for properties are:

```
svn propset answer 42 window.c
property 'answer' set on 'window.c'
```

Sets a propety 'answer' on file window.c to value 42.  You're probably not wanting to use this.

```
svn proplist window.c
Properties on 'window.c':
  svn:keywords
  svn:eol-style
  answer
```

Lists all of the properties (without values) on the file.

```
svn propget answer window.c
42
```

Gets the value of a specific property.

```
svn propedit answer window.c
Set new value for property 'answer' on 'window.c'
```

Opens up an editor (on my machine it's nano of all things) and lets you edit the property, then sets it on the given file.

```
svn propdel answer window.c
property 'answer' deleted from 'window.c'.
```

Deletes the specified property (this probably won't resolve your problem, my guess).

You can also do the `svn diff` to find out which property is different:

```
svn diff window.c
Index: window.c
===================================================================
--- window.c    (revision 35712)
+++ window.c    (working copy)

Property changes on: window.c
___________________________________________________________________
Added: answer
## -0,0 +1 ##
+42
\ No newline at end of property
```

This basically says that the only change here is a property 'answer' has been added, with value 42 (and no newline).

**So what I'd do**
Start with `svn diff` and find out what's changed:

```
svn diff controllers/database/udfs/searchForNameContSrch.sql
svn diff controllers/main
```

Have a google for the property that is changing and see if you can figure out what tool is setting it and turn it off.

You could try using `svn propdelete` to ditch the properties, but I don't think that's going to help.

**Failing that -- a quick revert script**

Otherwise, if you're using linux, this one liner will revert the files that have property modifications, but not content modifications.

**PLEASE TEST THIS ON NON-CRITICAL UPDATES THE FIRST TIME, YES?!?!?**

```
svn status | grep "^ M" | sed "s/^.\{8\}//" | while read rv; do svn revert $rv; done
```

That is:

- svn status
- pipe it through grep and filter for ONLY lines that start with ' M' (so it will ignore  'MM' - important).
- pipe it through sed and delete the first 8 characters (which are all the status columns before the file name).
- pipe that into a loop and revert the given file name.

Here it is in action:

```
svn status
 M      window.c
M       window.h
svn status | grep "^ M" | sed "s/^.\{8\}//" | while read rv; do svn revert $rv; done
Reverted 'window.c'
svn status
M       window.h
```

Comment: I hope we can find out what property was getting changed.  Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that those properties change when you **reintegrate back to trunk**, so I guess the property that changes is `svn:mergeinfo`, but you'd need to verify that.

Assuming the above, take a look at the following sources to understand what `mergeinfo` is and why you really **do** want to commit those changes. Also, it is possible to clean up those properties and not make them reappear again if you stick to a stricter merging process - i.e. always run the merge on trunk/branch root directory. This way `mergeinfo` will get recorded only on those directories, not on individual files. This has the benefit of not polluting your repo with `mergeinfo` scattered around, and also makes your commit diffs cleaner.

Sources:

- [SVN Book - Mergeinfo and Previews](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo)
- [SVN Book - Subtree Merges and Subtree Mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync.subtree)
- [Chris Oldwood - Cleaning up svn:mergeinfo Droppings](http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.com/2010/03/cleaning-up-svnmergeinfo-droppings.html)
- [How do I avoid large number of svn:mergeInfo when merging trunk to a feature-branch in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785743)
- [Remove unnecessary svn:mergeinfo properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767418)